# Why my javascript loop isn't working and make my chrome browser crash?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

UPDATED

I made this javascript script for my browser console and added a loop :

```
var available = false;
while (available === false){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('CONTENU_WIN').contentWindow.location.reload()
        setTimeout(function(){
            var button = document.getElementById('CONTENU_WIN').contentWindow.document.getElementById('boutonSuivant');
            button.click();
            setTimeout(function(){
                // Get value of span text
                var span_Text = document.getElementById('CONTENU_WIN').contentWindow.document.getElementById("compTableau_tbody").innerText;
                console.log(span_Text)
                if (span_Text == "No available appointment") {
                  console.log("NONNNNN");
                } else {
                    // If "No available appointment." not detected, it means that turnos are available. 
                    // Make a sound
                    var typeWriter = new Audio("http://soundbible.com/mp3/School_Fire_Alarm-Cullen_Card-202875844.mp3");
                    typeWriter.play()
                    // Date & Time instance
                    var ts = new Date();
                    console.log(ts.toString());
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        console.log("WAITING FOR YOUR TO TAKE THE TURNO!!!!")
                        }, 200000);
                    available = true;
                    console.log(available);
                }
            }, 5000);
        }, 10000);
    }, 10000);
}
```

My aim is to do the first "if" statement until it can't and go to the else (var available = true;)
But this loop makes my browser crash. I tested different loop and differents things :
- do / while
- while false/true
- for 
- setInterval
- ... but I can't understand why. Maybe i'm still not very confortable with loops.

Someone could help me on this please with ?
Thanks!

Comment: Simply do `available = true` (without var), instead of re-declare it.

Comment: I updated, it still crash

Comment: setTimeout is NOT a sleep method. The loop keeps running and running and making more timeouts. Asynchronous 101.

Comment: @Coline, you have a logical mistake into your code. `available` variable will become eventually true after more than 10 seconds because of all these `setTimeouts`. During that time your while loop is executing over and over again and simply overload the memory.

Comment: Ok, i used setTimeouts as i'm waiting for frames to load. Is there another method i can use then ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are reassigning the scope of  your variable `available`. The  var available = true; inside your function is a second allocated variable which is only available inside the function.

Comment: Hi! I edited this part now, and it still crash after launching the function